# Method called on an object when displayed on the console in Ruby

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I am willing to call a method when trying to display an object, but I don't find which method is used, for example:

```
[41] pry(main)> u
=> {"id"=>3}
[42] pry(main)> u.inspect
=> "#<User id=3>"
[43] pry(main)> u.to_s
=> "#<User id=3>"
[44] pry(main)> puts c
#<User id=3>
=> nil
```

I would like to know which method is called for the first case.

User is not an ActiveRecord class, it inherits from Hashie.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the rails method `attributes` - though it is a feature of Pry, not of the standard rails console which would give you `ruby-1.9.2-p290 :047 > u
 => #<u:0x8a2f6cc @id=3>`

Comment: +1, it seems that you right - 'Returns a hash of all the attributes with their names as keys and the values of the attributes as values.'at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not a Rails ActiveRecord Object, I don't use Rails here. Its a class that inherit from Hashie